# Issue accessing a dictionary key in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

When I execute this code:

```
df_settings = {
    "headers" : [
        "Header 1",
        "Header 2",
        "Header 3"
    ],
    "headers_type" : {
        "Header 1" : "int64",
        "Header 2" : "object",
        "Header 3" : "float"
    },
}

class DataframeValidator:
    
    def __init__(self, df_data, df_settings):
        self.df_data = df_data
        self.df_settings = df_settings
        
    def _check_missing_headers(self):
        """ controlla le che ci siano le intestazioni di colonna necessarie"""
        output_msg = ""
        missing_headers = []
        standards_headers = self.df_settings['headers']
        print(standards_headers)
        for header in standards_headers:
            if header in self.df_data.columns.tolist():
                continue
            else:
                missing_headers.append(header)
        if missing_headers:
            output_msg = f"Missing headers check failed: missing headers have been detected:\n {missing_headers}"
            return (False, output_msg)
        else:
            output_msg = "Missing headers check passed: no missing headers have been detected."
            return(True, output_msg)
        
        
    def _check_wrong_types(self, **kwargs):
        """ controlla le che ci siano le intestazioni di colonna necessarie"""
        print('_check_wrong_types') 
                
    rules = {
        'headers' : _check_missing_headers,
        'headers_type' : _check_wrong_types
    }       
    
    def validate_data_frame(self):
        output_msg = ""
        for setting in self.df_settings:
            if setting in self.rules:
                output = self.rules[setting](self.df_settings[setting])
                output_msg += str(output)
        print(output_msg)
        
        
dataframe_path = Path('test.xlsx')
dati = pd.read_excel(dataframe_path)
validator = DataframeValidator(dati, df_settings)
validator.validate_data_frame()
```

I obtain this error:

```
  File "/Users/manuelzompetta/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Lactalis/_SPOOL OneDrive/Test/datavalidator3.py", line 30, in _check_missing_headers
    standards_headers = self.df_settings['headers']
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'df_settings'
```

I do not understand where the mistake is, before I thought it depending from an issue related to the dictionary loaded by a json file. The purpose of the code is validating a dataframe applying some functions with parameters contained in a json file.

Comment: What do you think happens here `output = self.rules[setting](self.df_settings[setting])` for the `'headers'` key?

Comment: You're essentially calling `DataframeValidator._check_missing_headers` statically, passing it a list as `self` argument.

Comment: What I want to implement is execute `DataframeValidator._check_missing_headers`  that checks if `self.df_settings['headers']` > ["Header 1",...] are present as headers of the columns in a dataframe. I do not understand what is the issue with 'self'

Comment: There's nothing special about the name `self`. It's just the naming convention of the first argument in a method that _typically_ gets passed the instance. That's not happening here. You're not calling `self._check_missing_headers()` or `some_instance._check_missing_headers()`. You're calling `DataframeValidator._check_missing_headers(["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"])` which does _not_ pass an instance. It's passing the `list` and assigning it to `self`.

Comment: @Axe319 how can I send the instance and not the class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function within a `class`, they act as methods on that `class` and can be called with dot notation. (`Foo.bar()`) Other than that, they basically act as regular functions and any arguments you pass are assigned to the parameters.

When you instantiate that `class`, (`foo = Foo()`), methods called on that instance (`foo.bar()`) are *bound* to the instance. What this means is, python tries to be helpful and calls the method and passes the instance it was called on to the first argument. Typically named `self`.

To simplify your example:

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print(self, "In bar")
                
    rule = {
        'bar' : bar # here, Foo.bar is not bound to any instance
    }       
    
    def baz(self):
        print(self.bar, self.rule['bar'])
        # <bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000020BD3CB6750>> <function Foo.bar at 0x0000020BD3CA8860>
        
        
foo = Foo()
foo.baz()
```

At this point, you can see that `self.rule['bar']` actually references the method on the `class`, not the instance. You can still call it with the instance, simply by passing `self` as the argument to the method.

```
self.rule['bar'](self)
# is the same as
self.bar()
```

However, in your example, `self.df_settings[setting]` references a `list`. Since you are calling a regular method on the `class`, *not* the instance, it assigns that `list` to the `self` in `def _check_missing_headers(self):`.

I would guess what you want is something along the lines of `output = self.rules[setting](self)`.

Comment: You are totally right. The clue was in `output = self.rules[setting](self)` where I insisted to pass some arguments without any reason. After, why putting `(self)` is not totally clear to me because in other code I did, calling an helper function inside a class didn't need `(self)` and all worked properly. Maybe this is due to the fact that this helper function accepted some arguments like `self._check_file(file_path, ".xlsx")`. I still have to understand a lot... :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culpirit

```py
    output = self.rules[setting](self.df_settings[setting])
```

You only have to replace it by

```py
    output = self.rules[setting](self)
```

Because the input of both `_check_missing_headers` and `_check_wrong_types` is a `DataframeValidator` object. Your code was passing a `list`.

I could not check if everything else works because the rest of the code is not reproducible (I don't have the xlsx file).

Let me also remind you that methods in a class can be called in two equivalent ways:

```
instance_of_class.method(arg1, arg2, ...)
# or, equivalently
name_of_class.method(instance_of_class, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

In your example you are technically using the second calling method, but obviously, since you are already inside the class, you can omit the `name_of_class.` at the front.

The second way of calling is called "static" because that's the normal way if you have defined a [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod). You can still call it as regular methods but the instance is not passed as a first argument.

Comment: It works! But I still do not understand unfortunately.

I mean, I create an object `validator` passing as init parameters 1) the dataframe to be checked `dati` and 2) a dictionary of parameters `df_settings`. 

Then I call the method `validate_data_frame`, this method cycles the `df_settings` keys and, if the key of `df_settings` is as well a key in `rules`, execute the method that is the value of the key in `rules` , passing to it as input the value of the key in `df_settings`. 

So I do not understand when you write : @Because the input of both _check_missing_header..."

Comment: Let's try to break down the wrong line. `self.rules[setting]` gets one method from `rules`, let's say we are in the first iteration of the loop so this is `_check_missing_headers`. Now look at the definition of that method: `def _check_missing_headers(self):` Ok so we need to figure out the type of `self` in that function. By convention this is obvious, but we can also prove it: inside there is a `self.df_settings` so `self` *must* be an instance of `DataframeValidator`. We conclude that the argument of that `_check_missing_headers` must be an object of type `DataframeValidator`.

Comment: Now let's go back to the function `validate_data_frame`. Looking inside its body we see that `self` also has type `DataframeValidator` hence this is a good input for `_check_missing_headers`.